# Wi-Fi not working in ubuntu 18.04LTS in any site any browser

Tags: wireless, 18.04, atheros

My Wi-Fi stopped working after installing updates with updater app.

System information:

- ASUS-U556UQK/i5-7200
- 4GB RAM
- 1TB HDD
- 2GB graphics card NVIDIA 940MX
- Wi-Fi hardware: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 with driver `ath10k_pci`
- Kernel 4.15.0-36-generic.

in terminal this is the result:

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: f0:03:8c:b6:d9:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical   wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci 
       driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic 
       firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 
       latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 
       wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 memory:ef200000-ef3fffff
```

Comment: sorry for that.i am very new this site.